# MATLAB: How to divide up a string according to a recurring number

Tags: string, matlab, conditional-statements, division

Good day.

Here is an example of a piece of literate I want to divide up:

```
str =      ["1 This is sentence one of verse one, "+ ...
            "2 This is sentence one of verse two. "+ ...
            "3 This is sentence two of verse three; "+ ...
            "1 This is sentence three of verse one? "+ ...
            "2 This is sentence four of verse two, "+ ...
            "3 this is sentence four but verse three!"];
```

Notice how the numbers start over, this indicates a new chapter started. How can I make a nx1 string where n=chapters. This is what the results should look like:

[image]

Help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't there be 3 lines (verses)? The picture shows 2 lines

Comment: Good eyes. Yes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You only need a little bit of string manipulation:

```
>> c=convertStringsToChars(str);
>> splitstring = split(str,c(1));
>> splitstring = splitstring(strlength(splitstring) > 0);
>> formattedstring = string(1:length(splitstring)).' + " " + c(1) + splitstring

formattedstring = 

  2×1 string array

    "1 1 This is sentence one of verse one, 2 This is sentence one of verse two. 3 This is sentence two of verse three; "
    "2 1 This is sentence three of verse one? 2 This is sentence four of verse two, 3 this is sentence four but verse three!"
```